# Как сократить двойной цикл For?

Tags: python, django

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CardsDesk)
def create_cards_for_deck(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        
        cards = []
        for card_type in CHOICES:
            for card in card_type[1]:
                card = Card(card_type=card[0], deck=instance)
                cards.append(card)
        
        Card.objects.bulk_create(cards)
```

Меня очень напрягает двойной цикл for, я примерно понимаю как можно сократить эти два цикла, даже пробовал что-то типа:

```
cards = (Card(card_type=card[0], deck=instance)for card in card_type[1]) for card_type in CHOICES))
```

Но, код не срабатывает, есть идеи как сократить данную позицию как во втором примере?

Comment: `for card in (card_type[1] for card_type in CHOICES):`?

Comment: Чем у вас является `card_type[1]`?  Непонятен внутренний цикл - вы `card` итерируете по `card_type[1]` и тут же ему присваиваете вновь создаваемый объект?

Comment: @DmitryK  да, примерно об этом и идет код

Comment: @gil9red Довольно неплохое решение, но тут больше эстетика джанги волнует, я понимаю, что данный кусок кода, можно завернуть всего в 2 строки, в первой будет выполняться генератор, во второй создание обьектов